# My App crashes after being installed in my iPhone for a few days

Tags: ios, crash-reports

In the first few days,everything is running ok.But after then if I click my App to run it, it will crash immediately.

Edit: If I install it again with Xcode, it's ok again, it's a cycle...

Here is the crash report I got:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 12.2 (Build 16E227)
Architecture:    arm64
Report Version:  28

Data Source:     KPerf Lightweight PET
Kernel Cache:    0xffffffe000000000 53367679-EAC3-F9BC-B3A1-9B4AB7EBF3CC
Shared Cache:    0x23f0c000 BFBB889C-67F5-3193-9F53-E9429CB8D4A4
Reason:          UIKit-runloop-SpringBoard: timeout 931ms

Command:         SpringBoard
Path:            /System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Version:         ??? (???)
PID:             52

Duration:        0.90s
Steps:           18 (50ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  N71mAP
Active cpus:     2
```

What's the possible reason for this? I cann't find out which part of my code   is broken, so it is hard to post my code here. And I am hoping to locate the problem with only this crash report.

Comment: What certificicate do you have? The free one? a dev one?

Comment: @Larme The free one

Comment: That’s normal then. The validity of an app installes through Xcode with a free account is a few day. Through Testflight it’s 90 days, etc.

Comment: Oh, although I've been iOS/Mac developer for a few years, never knew that, thanks.